# Short story about a sentient house which dreams

Tags: story-identification

I’m trying to recall the name and author of a story called something like “The Dreams of Houses”.

It concerns a bachelor and how his smart house’s AI manipulates his relationship since it determines that his girlfriend is not good for him.

It takes place in a world with matter printing, building up any desired goods from atoms. He wants a blue car that day but he is out of cobolt; elements are delivered from a service.  All the household goods and decor and furnature are made and remade on demand.

He can make money by designing *plans* for (e.g.) vehicles.

People leave messages on telephones that stay at home, so that probably dates it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like it could be ["The Dream of Houses"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43632) by Wil McCarthy.

Specific elements (no pun intended), like cobalt, seem to match your memory:

> I am about to fax up my usual army of cleaning devices, when I realize that Chuck has driven away with most of my iron and titanium, and a good share of the staple elements as well, carbon and nitrogen and hydrogen and oxygen bound up in the plush, organic polymers of the automobile interior. I am not used to faxing anything so big, I really don’t have the resources for it.
>
> I put a call in to the Elementals, request standard shipments of all the elements I’ve run low on, and a double on the cobalt. Where does cobalt go? I am always coming up short in the evenings when I digest the day’s used faxware. Does Chuck leave a cobalt trail behind him in his daily wanderings? Chromium is almost as bad. I order some of that as well.

And selling designs for vehicles:

> Lucy smiles and shakes her head. “Self-employed, my darling. Like most of the rest of the world. You could work on your aircraft designs, like you’re always talking about. There’s always good money in vehicle specs.”
>
> “Yeah,” he says. “I guess there is. I guess that could work. Maybe.” He crashes, suddenly looking miserable again. “I don’t know. What about—”

However, the story does seem to lack the house trying to remove the girlfriend, although it does attempt to make some subtle manipulations:

> People often like to open doors for themselves, to prove in a small way that they are not helpless, that they do not actually need machines to take care of them. In this instance, though, the protocol is iffy; I sense that whoever holds the doorknob will hold power in this conversation—power to slam, to silence, to hurt. Certainly, I cannot give that kind of control to Lucy at the expense of my owner, but Chuck is not himself tonight, and it seems unwise to put the power in his hands, either. As Chuck is reaching for the knob I open the door myself, and suddenly he and Lucy are face-to-face.

and

> “Us?” He looks surprised, and pleased in a fragile and tentative way. “Is there an us?”
>
> CUE VIOLINS.
>
> Oh, that is awful, melodramatic. I haven’t been minding the music, and now I must pay the price, scrambling to keep it in the background.

But ultimately the two get back together and the house seems happy:

> I do not understand what has happened, cannot grasp the complex emotional shifts that have taken place here tonight. But I know that what’s happened is good, and that it will bring nothing but goodness upon all of us. This thought fills me with joy and confidence.
>
> I do not want Chuck and Lucy to feel themselves observed or intruded upon; a good house knows when to butt out.

Comment: Ah yes. I did not know of Wil when I read that in the magazine. But I recognise the fax theme from the later *Queendom* series, in retrospect.

Comment: Perhaps the AI erasing messages is from a different story.